# What is our stance on "where can I rent X in location Y" questions?

Tags: discussion, scope

What is our stance on "where can I rent X in location Y" questions?  Are they on-topic or off-topic?

I see many such questions on https://travel.stackexchange.com/search?q=Where+can+I+rent+, which seem to be typically upvoted. But this question on [renting a computer monitor](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/120941/1810) has been placed on hold as off-topic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I voted not to close the question and now also to reopen it. For me it's on topic as it's a problem that some business traveler will face.

Comment: I agree and my vote did re-open the question.